# Can't enabling java in Sybase ase 16

Tags: java, jvm, sybase, ase

i tried enabling java in sybase ase 16
using:

```
sp_configure "enable java", 1
```

but after restart the Sybase service i got:

> Incorrect Java Virtual Machine library version. Found 0, expected 41792701

and the ase server couldn't start.

what is the problem and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like incorrect installlation of the software, e.g some wrong binary files (or 32/64 bit clash) or something like that.
Do a full clean install of the software; if it doesn't help you'll need to contact rechsupport.